# how to call remote web service with use of javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jsonp

I have call web service of other site and use it in my site through JavaScript or Jquery or other JavaScript framework.
how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly what I'd call specific but I guess you are looking for something like $.ajax in jQuery. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for explanation and examples.

Comment: but this method only used when web service is published in your application, but i want to call web service from other site like for weather for cast.

Comment: What makes you think this isn't capable of cross-domain AJAX? I used this with several APIs (flickr mainly) by now and it always worked fine. See the cat example at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/